# insert multiple record to a table with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to insert the records (that i got from a table) to another table using codeigniter.
here's the function to add the record. I pass the $nokw to insert to another table as foreign key.:

```
function add_detail($nokw){
    $id_sj = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $upddate = date('Y')."-".date('m')."-".date('d')." ".date('H').":".date('i').":".date('s');
    $i=0;
    $this->suratjalan->where('IDDeliveryNo',$id_sj);
    $rec = $this->suratjalan->get("t02deliveryno_d")->result_array();

    // parse the result and insert it into an array 
    foreach ($rec as $det){
    $i++;
        $detail[$i] = array(
            'ID' => '',
            'NoKwitansi' => $nokw,
            'TypeProduct'=> $det['TypeProduct'],
            'PartNo' => $det['PartNo'],
            'PartNoVendor'=> $det['PartNoVendor'],
            'SerialPanel' => $det['SerialPanel'],
            'Description' => $det['Description'],
            'Dimension'   => $det['Dimension'],
            'DescriptionVendor' => $det['DescriptionVendor'],
            'DimensionVendor' => $det['DimensionVendor'],
            'PrintedProduct' => $det['PrintedProduct'],
            'Qty' => $det['Qty'],
            'UoM' => $det['UoM'],
            'Remark' => $det['Remark'],
            'UpdUser'=>  $this->session->userdata('user'),
            'UpdDate'=> $upddate
        );

        // insert the record
        $this->finance->insert('t02fkpd',$detail[$i]);
    }
}
```

It works, but it doesn't work if more than one row is returned from the table 't02deliveryno_d'. I think the error comes when i insert the record. i use the `$i++`to make different index in `$detail` array.

How can I fix this to properly insert multiple rows?

Comment: Please show the database schema for the `t02fkpd` table.

Comment: can you tell me how to show it? Sorry I really newbie here. can i show it by screenshot?

Comment: I can't upload the scheme.. :/

Comment: I solved it by using query INSERT...SELECT. thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show the db schema, but I'm assuming that `t02fkpd.ID` is an auto-incrementing column.

If that's the case, the problem is that you're specifying a blank value for `ID` instead of letting the database handle it. This is probably resulting in attempts to insert duplicate rows with the same (blank) id.

Here's an updated version of your function that I suspect will work better:

```
function add_detail($nokw) {
    $id_sj = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $upddate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $this->suratjalan->where('IDDeliveryNo',$id_sj);
    $rec = $this->suratjalan->get("t02deliveryno_d")->result_array();
    foreach ($rec as $det) {
        $details = array(
            'NoKwitansi' => $nokw,
            'TypeProduct'=> $det['TypeProduct'],
            'PartNo' => $det['PartNo'],
            'PartNoVendor'=> $det['PartNoVendor'],
            'SerialPanel' => $det['SerialPanel'],
            'Description' => $det['Description'],
            'Dimension'   => $det['Dimension'],
            'DescriptionVendor' => $det['DescriptionVendor'],
            'DimensionVendor' => $det['DimensionVendor'],
            'PrintedProduct' => $det['PrintedProduct'],
            'Qty' => $det['Qty'],
            'UoM' => $det['UoM'],
            'Remark' => $det['Remark'],
            'UpdUser'=>  $this->session->userdata('user'),
            'UpdDate'=> $upddate
        );
        $this->finance->insert('t02fkpd',$details);
    }
}
```

Beyond removing the `ID` value, I also made the following minor changes:

1. I removed `$i` and just reused the same variable for building the array of values to insert. You're not using the array after you insert, so there's no need to build a list of *all* the rows - you can just overwrite it each time.
2. I changed your the `$upddate` calculation to only call [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) once. You can specify an entire format string in one call - you're not restricted to just a single character at a time.

Comment: that's my previous version before I add $i autoincrement. :D
and that was not work.

Comment: Including without the `ID` value in the array?

Comment: do you need the db scheme to help me?

Comment: I think it might help. (I was actually just writing a comment on the question itself asking for it).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't get your question properly. But i think http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert with definitely help you.

You can make a array and pass it to `insert_batch` function with the table name and array. This will definitely help you.

if you must have checked `user-guide` for codeigniter. its one of the good documentation, where each and every function is documented.